# Tsql nvarchar date update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, nvarchar

I have a table(`tabl`) with column(`Col`) that is `nvarchar(10)` data type.

I am not suppose to change the data type or data length. The column contains date in this format `yyyy-mm-dd` (2012-04-24) I need to update that column to `mm/dd/yyyy`(04/24/2012).

Comment: Ugh. Why? That change will stop you from being able to sort sensibly within the database if you want to. Why not do the reformat in business logic?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `nvarchar`? Why not storing them as `Date` or `DateTime`?

Comment: I don't know the background but anyone with database experience will tell you it is a very bad idea to store dates as characters, and the fact that you need to go through and reformat them is just one symptom.

Comment: i agree with @MahmoudGamal and matt you should really not store dates as anything other than date type.

Comment: I changed the data type to datetime and used the UPDATE tabl SET col = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(col AS datetime), 101) given by Tass still the same result not getting the desired format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an awful set of constraints, but what you're asking is possible:

```
UPDATE tabl SET col = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(col AS datetime), 101)
```

The `101` at the end is the appropriate date style grabbed from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

The result is, though, that you'll have dates that are difficult to order and are format ambiguous. Storing as a `datetime` is the respectable thing to do.

Comment: Thank you Tass. I changed the data type to datetime and used the UPDATE tabl SET col = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), CAST(col AS datetime), 101) given by Tass still the same result not getting the desired format

Comment: OK, now you're asking a different question. My answer was to convert the string format in the database. Now that you're storing as datetime, you need to format the date/time for display somewhere in your application - `datetime` isn't formatted in the database. You should close off this question and research date formatting in whatever language you're using.